# Is there an O(n) way to find all indices of a value in an array?

Tags: java, algorithm

## Requirement

- find all indices in `new int[]{2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3}`
- The time complexity is within `O(n)`

## Example

- The index of 1 are 1, 3, 6
- The index of 2 are 0, 5
- The index of 3 are 2, 7
- The index of 4 are 4

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

1. Iterate your array and use a key-value paired Data structure to store one item as a key and its indexes as value.
2. Eventually at the end you would get all items and their corresponding indexes.
3. now you can either return the key-value paired DS or you can explore it as your requirements.

Basically, you are iterating the array n-number of times where n-is the total elements present in the array. So overall complexity is: `O(n)`

```
   int [] arr = new int[]{2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3};
   

    Map<Integer, List<>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
       for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
          if(hashMap.contains(arr[i])){
               hashMap.put(arr[i], hashMap.get(arr[i]).add(i);
          }else{
               hash.put(arr[i], new ArrayList<>());
          }
       }
    
       // at the end you would have a map that contains indexes of every item
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Why didn't I come up with this idea right away... Thank you so much.

Comment: Why are you using `new`? I think it's best to stick to psuedocode, but otherwise it'd be best to state the language.